# binding data to textbox as default c#

Tags: c#, data-binding

I dont know how to bind. Please help me thanks.

```
private void LoadtxtYear()
{
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
   string sql = "";
   sql = "SELECT  COCOPER  FROM HR11COMP  where cocode = '" + sComCode + "' order by COCPER";
   if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Open(); }

   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
   da.Fill(ds, "temp");

   txtYear.DataBinding.Add("Text", ds.Tables["temp"], "COCPER");
}
```

Comment: To me, you've answered your own question.

Comment: Binding is the least of your worries with this code.  First, you should consider checking out the "using" statement (related to IDisposable).  The dataset, connection, and adapter need to be disposed if you want to avoid memory leaks.   Also are you expecting only 1 record?  if so, you should use ExecuteScalar.  That said, you should probably just set the Text property of the textbox if you plan to do this in code.  I'll post you a better sample for data access as an answer.

Comment: Also, SQL injection is quite possible with this kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like this:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT  COCOPER  FROM HR11COMP  where cocode = @sComCode order by COCPER";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sComCode", sComCode));

                object cocoper = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (cocoper != null)
                     txtYear.DataBinding.Add("Text", cocoper.ToString(), "COCPER");
            }
        }
```